# Cannot install eclipse under ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm searching all over the internet and cannot find an answer to this,
I tried to configure but this error keeps happening

[image: this is happening]

Comment: Try askubuntu this is the wrong place for this question. Also do you have access to the internet like the installer asks?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to the internet right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information to determine anything other than the fact that the application isn't communicating with the server. The server could be not functioning, you could have any number of things blocking your connection between the program and the server.
The best advice I can give it to check that you can connect to the internet and that you have no weird firewall settings.
You could run Wireshark on your computer to see if you can stop the destination and ports, and then re-check your firewall.

Comment: OK, that was helpful, I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I run apt-get update, and it started to work.